# How do I add my program to the users start menu with VS2010 Setup Project?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

**How do I add my program to the users start menu with VS2010 Setup Project?**

I don't see an obvious place to do this.

What would be even better than this is a link to a reference that holds my hand through setting up projects so I can see how it is supposed to be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add a short cut in to the executable in the File System view.

[image]

More steps [here](http://www.courtesyindia.com/software/tips-and-tricks/create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-a-visual-studio-2010-setup-project-dot)

[image]

Comment: User's Programs Menu wasn't showing up in my file system view.  You have to right click on the "File System on Target Machine" and choose to show it first.  Nice image tho.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that ... you need to sat the Target to be Application Folder\Primary Output

Comment: @CharithJ the icon changes in the desktop shortcut but not change for the start button. any suggestion?

Comment: Look at User's Program Menu properties and check the icon? Make sure you install the correct build debug/release. Uninstall the application and reinstall.

Answer (score 49):

1. Go to `Application Folder`, look on the right hand side it should say, `Primary output from X` (make sure you don't have other widgets covering up this real estate.)
2. Right click that => make shortcut
3. Go to `User's Program's Menu` ==> create the folder that you want your shortcut to reside in, probably your company name
4. Drag the shortcut from step 2 to the folder you just created.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Setup Project File System*, right-click the *User's Programs Menu*, and create a folder for your application.  Go to the *Application Folder*, right-click project output, then select *Create Shortcut to xxx*.  Drag the shortcut to the application folder.

Answer (score 4):

After wasting an hour, I got it done - VS 2010 (this article helped):

In your Deployment Project go to File System Editor
Click on "Application Folder" (I assume you have "Primary Output" from your projects there)
Right click on "Primary Output" of the project you want to target with your shortcut - select "Create Shortcut to Primary Output ..."
Rename shortcut
Drag shortcut to Desktop / Programs Menu folder
That's it!

Comment: Step by step procedure to follow :)
http://www.courtesyindia.com/software/tipsandtricks/Publish.aspx?Select1=Create%20a%20desktop%20shortcut%20in%20a%20Visual%20studio%202010%20Setup%20project%20dot

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the setup project and click View -> File System.  There is a foler there for User's Programs Menu.  You can add a shortcut to your project's executable there.

[Here](http://courtesyindia.com/Software-Documet-Sample-Code/Create%20a%20desktop%20shortcut%20in%20a%20Visual%20studio%202010%20Setup%20project%20dot%20.aspx) is a link that walks you through the process.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the shortcut at the top level of the start menu is not really standard behavior. The shortcut should be created in the folder [Manufacturer][ProductName] in the user's "Programs" menu. However, it seems you can't use the installer properties in the Visual Studio deployment proje

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

1. Right click on "Application Folder", click on "Properties", then change "AlwaysCreate" to true.
2. right click on "Application Folder" and click "Create Shortcut to Application Folder"
3. Rename the "Shortcut to Application Folder" to whatever name you choose.
4. Drag that shortcut into the "User's Desktop" or "User's Programs menu".
5. Build the project.
6. You're done! :)